# How to replace udp packets on the fly?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, udp

I've used iptables to reroute traffic to netsed [like this](https://serverfault.com/a/321671), but it seems to route the traffic to another location.

I've used hexinject like this:

```
hexinject -s -i eth0 -c 1 -f 'arp' | replace '06 04 00 01' '06 04 00 02' | hexinject -p -i eth0
```

but the problem with hexinject is that it only injects, it doesn't replace the original packet, it just sends another one.

I've also used ettercap + etterfilter, but it doesn't seem to replace the traffic:

```
if (ip.proto == UDP) {
   if (search(DATA.data, "\x1f\x0f\x00\x08\x00\x01")) {
      log(DATA.data, "/tmp/payload");
      drop();
      execinject("/bin/sed s/\x1f\x0f\x00\x08\x00\x01/\x1f\x0f\x00\x08\x00\x00/g' /tmp/payload");
      msg("caught!");   
   }
}
```

What I want to do is replace the hex representation of `1f 0f 00 08 00 01` to `1f 0f 00 08 00 00`, just changing the last bit to zero, but I was unable to get iptables + netsed, hexinject, or ettercap + etterfilter to work.

Here's a visualization:

Server attempts to send `1f 0f 00 08 00 01` to someone, a program changes so that `1f 0f 00 08 00 00` is sent instead.

What can I try next? Or maybe I'm using these programs in the wrong way.

Comment: Heck with `hexinject` and other possible tools. Formulate the problem (what to be achieved) from the beginning, please; and don’t expect me following to the bullies’ site even by direct links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HexInject and just add a firewall rule to block the forwarding of that specific packet.

Easy and simple.

An example using IPTables to block UDP packets to port 53:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --destination-port 53 -j DROP
```

If you instead want to filter at layer2, you can give a look at [EBTables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/).

It is a sort of firewall for layer 2 frames.